# Dotnet Angular template and Core 2.0 MVC

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, angular-cli, dotnet-cli

After some reading about Angular, I am still confused about several things.

1. When using "dotnet new Angular", what Angular version is integrated with the created solution? There are some blogs explain why you would integrate an SPA to an MVC Core solution, but no one has explained why they haven't used Angular template on dotnet 2.0 instead.
2. Apparently there are people who still call Angular 4 with 2 instead. Why?
3. How Visual Studio 2017 (Win and Mac versions) can run Angular apps?

Thanks

Comment: I feel your pain.  I'm still chasing around for ways to integrate Angular 4 and .NET Core.  This was my starting point -> https://dotnetcore.gaprogman.com/2017/04/20/dotnet-new-angular-single-page-application-setup-and-how-the-template-works/

Comment: As for dotnet new angular - I think its down to the latest version of .net templates you install - ala `dotnet new --install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates::*`

Comment: If you install the WebPack Task Runner (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebPackTaskRunner) you will see the config in the Task Runner Explorer.  Now as far as I am concerned, WebPack is like voodoo magic.  The Angular Cli uses web pack to generate the application resources.  I'm still trying to understand everything too, but its quite comprehensive so probably will take me some time.  When you run from the debug menu, it will start debugging the solution like normal.  You can debug the typescript in Chrome which is pretty cool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In the generated project you can find the Angular library versions in the package.json file at the "dependencies". I just tried it, and it generated the latest Angular versions.
2. Angular 2 and Angular 4 is compatible. Apparently there is not so much difference between Angular 2 and 4, I think that's why some people call Angular 4 still Angular 2. (There is a huge difference between Angular 1.X and Angular 2+, thats why Angular 1.X is called "AngularJS" and Angular 2+ "Angular"). 
   Details:
   https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Angular-2-and-Angular-4
3. Visual Studio uses Webpack to build the Angular application. The mechanism is like you would use the Angular CLI.